# Sumar valores de una columna que se cumpla la condición de otras dos columnas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo éste dataframe

```
open_positions=pd.DataFrame({
  'ticket':[25,40,55,60,80,45] , 
  'profit': [10.00,5.00,4.00,6.00,3.00,2.00], 
  'comment':['','','CT40,'CT55','','']})
```

```
ticket  profit  comment
25       10.00    ""
40        5.00    ""
55        4.00    "CT40"
60        6.00    "CT55"    
80        3.00    ""
45        2.00    ""
```

ticket es int
profit es float
comment es string

Necesito sumar "profit" siempre y cuando en "comment" NO se encuentre el ticket dentro, para éste ejemplo, el tiket 55 y el 40 quedarían fuera de la suma, el valor que quiero obtener es de 21.00 que es la suma de los tickets 25, 60, 80 y 45. Excluyendo de la suma los tickets 55 y 40 ya que se encuentra dentro de los comentarios del 55 y 60.

Intente esto

```
open_positions[not open_positions.comment.str.contains(str(open_positions['ticket']))]['profit'].sum()
```

Pero no funciono, con dos ciclos for lo puedo hacer, pero sin ciclos for sería ideal.

Agradeciendo de antemano su valiosa ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Por qué no te ha funcionado

Hay varios errores en tu intento:

1. Cuando estás escribiendo una expresión booleana como un selector de filas para pandas, no se pueden usar las keywords `and`, `or` ni `not`, pues estas operan sólo sobre valores booleanos "escalares" (o sea, no sobre series o dataframes). En su lugar debes usar `&`, `|` y `~` respectivamente. Por tanto lo que querías escribir debería haberse puesto así:

   ```
   open_positions[~open_positions.comment.str.contains(str(open_positions['ticket']))]['profit'].sum()
   ```
2. Esa expresión, auque ya es correcta sintácticamente, no hace lo que pretendías, sino que selecciona todas las filas de la tabla. Eso es por culpa de la parte que dice `str(open_positions['ticket'])`, pues si evalúas esto para ver qué saldría verás que el resultado es una sola cadena:

   ```
   "0    25\n1    40\n2    55\n3    60\n4    80\n5    45\nName: ticket, dtype: int64"
   ```

   Como ves esta cadena es en realidad lo que le has pedido: la representación textual de `open_positions['ticket']` en forma de cadena. Pero es falso para cualquier fila que el comment forme parte de esta cadena que acabamos de ver. Por ejemplo en la fila en la que el comment es "C40" tu expresión está preguntando si la cadena "C40" contiene a la cadena `"0   25\n1...etc"` lo cual es obviamente falso.

   Ya que en todas las filas es falso, y el `~`  que hace de "not" lo revierte, acabas seleccionando todas las filas, y el resultado es 30.0, no lo que querías.

### Solución

Depende un poco de qué tengas exactamente en tu columna `comment`. ¿Realmente todos los comments tienen una estructura regular compuesta por dos letras seguidas de un número, o bien una cadena vacía? Quizás en ese caso lo más apropiado sería procesar previamente esa columna para extraer lo que son solamente los números, y construir con ellos un conjunto:

```
numeros_a_excluir = set([int(c[2:]) for c in open_positions.comment if c])
```

En tu ejemplo el resultado en esta variable sería: `{40, 55}`

Ahora ya podemos aplicar algo similar a tu idea original:

```
open_positions[~open_positions.ticket.isin(numeros_a_excluir)].profit.sum()
```

y el resultado es `21.0` como querías.

### Alternativa

Si la columna "comment" no tiene una estructura tan regular, otra posibilidad es concatenar todos los contenidos de esa columna en una cadena:

```
a_excluir = " ".join(open_positions.comment)
```

En este caso se obtiene la cadena `"  CT40 CT55  "`

Y después se puede ver si cada elemento de la columna "ticket", convertido a cadena, aparece dentro de la cadena `a_excluir`. Para esto lo mejor es aplicar una lambda sobre cada fila:

```
open_positions[open_positions.apply(
                 lambda r: str(r.ticket) not in a_excluir, axis=1)
              ].profit.sum()
```

y también obtienes 21.0.

Incluso puedes hacer que la lambda, en vez de retornar True o False, retorne directamente el valor de profit o bien 0, y sumar los resultados. Así:

```
open_positions.apply(
    lambda r: r.profit if str(r.ticket) not in a_excluir else 0, axis=1
  ).sum()
```

Comment: de hecho comment solo es vacio o tiene la estructura CT seguida de un numero que esta en tiket siempre, adapte la última solución proporcionada lambda r: r.profit if str(r.ticket) not in " ".join(open_positions.comment) else 0, axis=1
  ).sum(), para que se en una sola línea y ya dio el resultado deseado. Agradezco el apoyo.

Comment: No siempre una sola línea es la opción más eficiente, ni la más legible. Tu "one-liner" causa que el "".join() se ejecute de nuevo para cada fila, lo que no es necesario y se evita si sacas esa operación fuera de la lambda como había hecho yo. Por otro lado, buscar dentro de una cadena (como hace esta solución) es mucho más ineficiente que hacerlo dentro de un set. La primera solución es mucho más rápida (y lo notarás si tienes que procesar grandes volúmenes). Si confirmas que el comment tiene estructura regular, yo aconsejo la primera solución.